# stream unzip into split

Tags: bash, shell, split, unzip

I have a `zip` file which I want to split into multi `gzip` files. I don't need the actual file on disk and prefer to keep everything in memory so it will be faster. was thinking maybe:

```
split -C 2M -d -a 3 --filter 'gzip > $FILE.gz' <(unzip a.zip ) a_
```

or
unzip -c a.zip | split -C 2M -d -a 3 --filter 'gzip > $FILE.gz' a_

But it `gzip` the output of the unzip:

```
Archive:  a.zip
  inflating: data.txt
```

And on the second option it fails

```
split: cannot open ‘a_’ for reading: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-c -q` is the answer

```
split -C 2M -d -a 3 --filter 'gzip > $FILE.gz' <(unzip -c -q a.zip ) a_
```